# TypeError: undefined is not an object on react native app

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

the code below of my react native app needs to display a simple background image to do that I use in below code (I use css and js), when I run the code I get the following error, it tells me the width parameter is not defined though it is how do I solve this?

**Error Width React Native:**

```
    :19 in handleException
    at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
    at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:54:4 in renderApplication
    at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
    at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:213:4 in runApplication
    
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'style.width')
    
    This error is located at: 
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'style.width')

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at Router.js:101)
    in App (at Router.js:127)
    in Router (at App.js:8)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

**React Code:**

```
/* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
/* eslint-disable global-require */
/* eslint-disable react/destructuring-assignment */
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ImageBackground,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { login } from '../services/user';
import * as style from './style/design';

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  async login() {
    const ret = await login(this.state.username, this.state.password);
    if (ret === 'denied') {
      console.log(`Sono dentro con : ${ret.toString()}`);
    } else {
      Actions.home();
    }
  }

  gotoregister() {
    Actions.register();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source="../assets/images/backgroundhome.jpg"
          style={style.imgBackground}
        >
          <SafeAreaView>
            <TextInput
              style={style.textinput}
              onChangeText={(text) => {
                this.setState({ username: text });
              }}
              value={this.state.username}
              placeholder="insert username"
            />

            <TextInput
              style={style.textinput}
              onChangeText={(text) => {
                this.setState({ password: text });
              }}
              value={this.state.password}
              placeholder="insert password"
            />
            <Button title="Login" onPress={() => this.login()} />
            <Button
              title="Register to fit"
              onPress={() => this.gotoregister()}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

**design.js file:**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }
});

export const style = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    height: 100,
    width: 260
  },
  imgBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
  },
  textinput: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderColor: '#D3D3D3',
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

style.container is undefined. Try merging the styles in the design.js file.

```
export const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    flex: 1, 
    justifyContent: 'center' 
  },
  image: {
    height: 100,
    width: 260
  },
  imgBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
  },
  textinput: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderColor: '#D3D3D3',
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```